# ASM Try/Catch Block with an output value

Tags: java, try-catch, java-bytecode-asm, jvm-bytecode

I am currently trying make my custom compiler allow using `try/catch` as an expression, i.e. leaving a value on the stack. The type checker and the backend already support this, but the problem seems to be ASM's `COMPUTE_FRAMES`. With the below code for instrumentation:

```
private void write(MethodWriter writer, boolean expression)
{
    org.objectweb.asm.Label tryStart = new org.objectweb.asm.Label();
    org.objectweb.asm.Label tryEnd = new org.objectweb.asm.Label();
    org.objectweb.asm.Label endLabel = new org.objectweb.asm.Label();

    boolean hasFinally = this.finallyBlock != null;

    writer.writeLabel(tryStart);
    if (this.action != null)
    {
        if (expression && !hasFinally)
        {
            this.action.writeExpression(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            this.action.writeStatement(writer);
        }
        writer.writeJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, endLabel);
    }
    writer.writeLabel(tryEnd);

    for (int i = 0; i < this.catchBlockCount; i++)
    {
        CatchBlock block = this.catchBlocks[i];
        org.objectweb.asm.Label handlerLabel = new org.objectweb.asm.Label();

        // Check if the block's variable is actually used
        if (block.variable != null)
        {
            // If yes register a new local variable for the exception and
            // store it.
            int localCount = writer.registerLocal();

            writer.writeLabel(handlerLabel);
            writer.writeVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, localCount);
            block.variable.index = localCount;
            if (expression && !hasFinally)
            {
                block.action.writeExpression(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                block.action.writeStatement(writer);
            }
            writer.resetLocals(localCount);
        }
        // Otherwise pop the exception from the stack
        else
        {
            writer.writeLabel(handlerLabel);
            writer.writeInsn(Opcodes.POP);
            if (expression && !hasFinally)
            {
                block.action.writeExpression(writer);
            }
            else
            {
                block.action.writeStatement(writer);
            }
        }

        writer.writeTryCatchBlock(tryStart, tryEnd, handlerLabel, block.type.getInternalName());
        writer.writeJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, endLabel);
    }

    if (hasFinally)
    {
        org.objectweb.asm.Label finallyLabel = new org.objectweb.asm.Label();

        writer.writeLabel(finallyLabel);
        writer.writeInsn(Opcodes.POP);
        writer.writeLabel(endLabel);
        if (expression)
        {
            this.finallyBlock.writeExpression(writer);
        }
        else
        {
            this.finallyBlock.writeStatement(writer);
        }
        writer.writeFinallyBlock(tryStart, tryEnd, finallyLabel);
    }
    else
    {
        writer.writeLabel(endLabel);
    }
}
```

Compiling this code:

```
System.out.println(try Integer.parseInt("10") catch (Throwable t) 10)
```

I get the following `VerifyError` upon class loading:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 17
Exception Details:
  Location:
    dyvil/test/Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @14: goto
  Reason:
    Current frame's stack size doesn't match stackmap.
  Current Frame:
    bci: @14
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
    stack: { integer }
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @17
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
    stack: { top, integer }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 1412 16b8 001c a700 0957 100a a700
    0000010: 03b6 0024 b1                           
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [3, 11] => handler: 11
  Stackmap Table:
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@11,Object[#30])
    full_frame(@17,{Object[#38]},{Top,Integer})
```

Since I don't think that ASM has a problem computing the stack frames for `try/catch` blocks with an output value, is there a problem with my instrumentation code? (Note that `ClassWriter.getCommonSuperclass`, although it is not needed here, is correctly implemented.)

Comment: Short answer: there is a problem in your code. Obviously, ASM can calculate stackmap frames for *correct* code only. If, like with your code, a branch targets a location with an incompatible stack layout as indicated by the exception, there is nothing ASM could do to fix that.

Comment: Sure, but what exactly is the problem here? ASM is (understandably) not particularly helpful with errors in the bytecode generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, ASM can calculate stackmap frames for correct code only as no stackmap can fix broken code. We can learn what went wrong when we analyze the exception.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames at branch target 17
```

there is a branch targeting byte code position `17`.

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    dyvil/test/Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V @14: goto
```

the source of the branch is a `goto` instruction at position `14`

```
  Reason:
    Current frame's stack size doesn't match stackmap.
```

quite self explaining. The only thing you have to consider that non-matching frames don’t necessarily indicate a wrong stackmap calculation; it might be that the bytecode itself is violates the constraints and the calculated stackmap just reflects that.

```
  Current Frame:
    bci: @14
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
    stack: { integer }
```

at `14`, the source of the branch (the location of the `goto` instruction), the stack contains one `int` value.

```
  Stackmap Frame:
    bci: @17
    flags: { }
    locals: { '[Ljava/lang/String;' }
    stack: { top, integer }
```

at `17`, the target of the branch, are *two* values on the stack.

```
  Bytecode:
    0000000: b200 1412 16b8 001c a700 0957 100a a700
    0000010: 03b6 0024 b1
```

well, the bytecode isn’t disassembled here, but you can’t say the exception message was too brief up to this point. Manual disassembling the bytecode yields:

```
 0: getstatic     0x0014
 3: ldc           0x16
 5: invokestatic  0x001c
 8: goto          +9 (=>17)
11: pop
12: bipush        #10
14: goto          +3 (=>17)
17: invokevirtual 0x0024
20: return
```

```
  Exception Handler Table:
    bci [3, 11] => handler: 11
```

What we can see here is that there are two ways of reaching location `17`, one is the ordinary execution of `getstatic, ldc, invokestatic` the other is the exception handler, starting at `11`, performing `pop` `bipush`. We can deduce for the latter that it has indeed one `int` value on the stack as it pops the exception and pushes one `int` constant.

For the former, there is not enough information here, i.e. I don’t know the signature of the invoked method, however, since the verifier didn’t reject the `goto` from `8` to `17`, it’s safe to assume that the stack indeed holds two values before the branch. Since `getstatic, ldc` produces two values, the `static` method must have either a `void ()` or a `value (value)` signature. This implies that the value of the very first `getstatic` instruction is not used before the branch.

→After reading your comment, the error becomes apparent: that first `getstatic` instruction reads `System.out` which you want to use at the end of the method to invoke `println`, however, when an exception occurred, the stack is flushed and no `PrintWriter` is on the stack but the exception handler tries to recover and join the code path at the place where the `PrintWriter` is required for invoking `println`. It is important to understand that exception handlers *always* start with an operand stack consisting of a single element, the exception. None of the values you might have pushed before the exception occurred will persist. So if you want to prefetch a field value (like `System.out`) before the guarded code and use it regardless of whether an exception occurred, you have to store it in a local variable and retrieve afterwards.

It seems that ASM derived the stackmap frame for location `@17` from the state before the first branch and when joining it with the frame of the state before the second branch, it only cared for the types but not the different depth, which is a pity as it’s an error that is easy to spot. But it’s only a missing feature (as `COMPUTE_FRAMES` is not specified to do error checking), not a bug.

Comment: As I said, the the method inside the `try` block was `Integer.parseInt("10")`, with the signature `(Ljava/lang/String;)I`, which represents your `value (value)`. The output value of the `invokestatic` *is* used after all, *after* the `catch` block (in the invocation of `System.out.println(int)`). The problem here is that ASM has to 'forget' this value when entering the catch block, because the catch block will never enter when the try block returned a value, i.e. completed successfully.

Comment: Another thing to note is the fact that there is the `top` type in the generated stack frame, which normally shouldn't happen.

Comment: Stop blaming ASM. As explained, your code reaches the same location with different stack layouts, point. The only misunderstanding on my side was, that you actually *want* two values on the stack, so your exception handler’s code path is the wrong one as it has only one value. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, ok, i see. Since exception handlers always start with *one* value on the stack, the exception itself, it is not possible to have something else on the stack before entering the entire try/catch block. That is a pity, because it means that I cannot use `try/catch` blocks the way I want to use them in my code. However, a workaround might be to use a `private` method (capturing variables and such -.-) that contains the `try/catch` block, making the expression something like `System.out.println(this.try$1())`.

Comment: That should work but it’s not clear whether that’s simpler than introducing anonymous local variables for these values.

Comment: Also seems like an idea. Thanks.